# Puppet unzip file always into read only folder

Tags: linux, shell, puppet

I am using following script part to unzip my zip file. But the problem is it unzips the file always into a readonly folder. How can this be fixed.

```
exec { "install appliction server to pc":
command => 'unzip wso2as-5.2.1.zip',
cwd => '/home/malintha/adikari3/',
path      => '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin',
logoutput => true,
timeout => 3600,
require => File['/home/malintha/adikari3/wso2as-5.2.1.zip'],
}
```

Comment: Relates ServerFault question: http://serverfault.com/questions/540311/how-can-i-make-puppet-run-a-command-once

Answer (score 1):

There are three parameters to the `exec` type, of which you should use at least one, to control when and when not to run

- `onlyif`
- `unless`
- `creates`

The unzipping of an archive typically lends itself to a `creates` solution

```
exec { "unzip-file":
  cwd => "/path/for/extraction",
  creates => "/path/for/extraction/software-x.y",
  ...
}
```

assuming that the zip extracts into a directory tree rooted at `software-x.y`.

For more details, see the [reference documentation](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#exec-attribute-creates).